# TFS connection API

Tags: tfs

I am connecting to TFS using the following code, Can someone guide me on which API I should so that I dont have to provide user name , domain and pass.

Application should pick the windows credential through which I have logged in to the system.

TeamFoundationServer tfServer = new TeamFoundationServer(@"domain", new NetworkCredential("username", ","password", "domain"));

tfServer.Authenticate();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.defaultnetworkcredentials.aspx)?  Assuming you are on the same domain.

Answer (score 1):

I see this has already been answered, however, you can just omit the network credentials, and it will use the currently logged-in user.  e.g.:

```
var TfsServer = new TeamFoundationServer("http://tfs:8080");
```

Comment: Currently logged on user don't have rights.only a specific admin user has rights.What to do in this case.